# What does "It must be the pizza" mean ?

Tags: idioms, expressions

Is there an idiom such as "it must be the pizza" ? 
If so, does that mean something other than what it is ? 
very much Appreciated, : )

Comment: It's not an idiom. It needs a context. E.g., "Why is everybody puking?" "It must be the pizza. Everybody ate pizza." It means that the pizza is what's making everyone throw up. You can substitute anything for _pizza_ and the meaning will be the same: "The X is what's making everybody throw up", in this context. "It must be the..." is a standard phrase in English, though.

Answer (score 3):

“It must be the pizza” is not idiomatic, that is, its meaning  is not “illogical or separate from the meanings of its component words”.   However, as already suggested in a comment, the meaning is context dependent.  For example, if the doorbell rings and Alice says, “It must be the pizza”, then Bob will understand that she means a pizza has been ordered and has arrived and he has to pay for it.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can explain it to my gf !!! have a great day !